# Set up of TQuery's Database fails context of a created TSession

Tags: delphi, bde

Preface: BDE is deprecated. This work is a project to reduce its footprint in my shop. ;-)

I need to periodically move data in threads from a BDE TQuery to our Oracle instance. That requires the TQuery be configured with a TDatabase in its own, uniquely named TSession.

My draft code (below -- and not using a data module) creates a new session; then makes a database for that session that uses our common BDE alias for the directory with Paradox (!) tables. (Because it's draft and a test, niceties like the private directory, unique session naming, etc., aren't handled yet.) Then I create a TQuery, `Q`, and tell it to use the database and its session (via `DB`'s name).

And that's where it all goes bad. After adding SQL, `Q.Prepare` excepts with `Unknown alias`. Since `Q`'s `Database` is nil, that makes sense. NB: I've also tried `DB.Open` just before substantive work on `Q` -- no improvement.

I'm guessing that I've forgotten some plumbing; I've got the order of setup steps wrong; or the "default" session and its database matter -- none of those are set or used in this draft.

I'm stumped.

Thanks!

**Update**: add more of the code to clarify that the two procedures are part of a class.

```
uses
  Bde.DBTables,System.Classes,System.Generics.Collections;

type TUpdateFieldmap = class(TObject)
  private
    DB: TDatabase;
    UpdateSession: TSession;

    procedure GetTableFields;

  public
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;

    procedure OpenSis;
end;

const
    DBNAME  = 'fieldsets';
    SESSIONNAME='testsession';

implementation

procedure TUpdateFieldmap.GetTableFields;
var
  Q: TQuery;
begin
  Q := TQuery.Create(NIL);
  Q.DatabaseName := DBNAME;
  Q.SessionName := SESSIONNAME;

  // Q.Database is still undefined

  // ...
end;

procedure TUpdateFieldmap.OpenSis;
begin
  UpdateSession:=Sessions.OpenSession(SESSIONNAME);
  UpdateSession.ConfigMode:=cmAll;
  UpdateSession.NetFileDir := 'f:\public\DBShare\DBNet';

  DB := TDatabase.Create(NIL);

  DB.AliasName := 'si_production';
  DB.DatabaseName := DBNAME;

  DB.SessionName:=UpdateSession.SessionName;

  DB.Open;

  GetTableFields;
end;
```

Comment: `GetTableFields` is going to need the `UpdateSession` and `DB` you've set up in `OpenSis`. Pass them as parameters to that method.

Comment: Thanks, @KenWhite. An edit clarifies that those two procedures, and `DB` and `UpdateSession`, are members of a class.

Comment: How about instead of changing the code, you provide an actual [mcve] that can be copied, pasted and compiled?

Comment: @KenWhite is right.  You should provide an MCVE in a q like this.  People are far more likely to try and reproduce your problem if you provide one, rather than leaving them to guess the details you haven't supplied.